# association in rails 3 associate 1 survey to 1 user

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, associations

i'm working with ruby 1.9.2, rails 3.1.3, devise 1.5.3, mysql, my app is about surveys, now all users can see all surveys, but I need that user1 just could see surveys created by user1, now user1 and user2, etc. can see all surveys, the authentication module is done with devise, recognize every user by login, in my database I put user_id as foreign key, or just by alter table tablename add column user_id int(11)not null; but when I tried to create a new survey I get this message: **Mysql2::Error: Column 'user_id' cannot be null: INSERT INTO `asurveys` (`created_at`, `name`, `updated_at`, `user_id`) VALUES ('2012-02-29 12:39:34', 'encuesta musical', '2012-02-29 12:39:34', NULL)**
**my controller:**

**asurveys_controller.rb**

> class AsurveysController < ApplicationController   # GET /asurveys   #
>   GET /asurveys.json
>
> def index
>       @asurveys = current_user.asurveys
>         respond_to do |format|
>         format.html # index.html.erb
>         format.json { render json: @asurveys }
>       end   end
>
> ```
> @asurvey = Asurvey.find(params[:id])
> #@asurvey = current_user.asurveys.find(params[:id])
> #current_user.asurveys = User.find(1)
> respond_to do |format|
>   format.html # show.html.erb
>   format.json { render json: @asurvey }
> end   end
> ```
>
> # GET /asurveys/new   # GET /asurveys/new.json   #def new
>       #@asurvey = Asurvey.new
>       #3.times { @asurvey.questions.build }
>
> ```
> #respond_to do |format|
> #  format.html # new.html.erb
> #  format.json { render json: @asurvey }
> #end  #end   #ejemplo railscast para 3 preguntas y 4 respuestas   def new  
>       @asurvey = Asurvey.new
> ```
>
> 3.times do
>       question = @asurvey.questions.build
>       4.times { question.answers.build }     end   end   #
>       # GET /asurveys/1/edit   def edit
>       @asurvey = Asurvey.find(params[:id])   end
>
> # POST /asurveys   # POST /asurveys.json   def create
>           @asurvey = Asurvey.new(params[:asurvey])
>
> ```
> respond_to do |format|
>   if @asurvey.save
>     format.html { redirect_to @asurvey, notice: 'Encuesta creada exitosamente.' }
>     format.json { render json: @asurvey, status: :created, location: @asurvey }
>   else
>     format.html { render action: "nueva" }
>     format.json { render json: @asurvey.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
>   end
> end   end
> ```
>
> # PUT /asurveys/1   # PUT /asurveys/1.json   def update
>       @asurvey = Asurvey.find(params[:id])
>
> ```
> respond_to do |format|
>   if @asurvey.update_attributes(params[:asurvey])
>     format.html { redirect_to @asurvey, notice: 'Encuesta actualizada exitosamente.' }
>     format.json { head :ok }
>   else
>     format.html { render action: "editar" }
>     format.json { render json: @asurvey.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
>   end
> end   end
> ```
>
> # DELETE /asurveys/1   # DELETE /asurveys/1.json   def destroy
>       @asurvey = Asurvey.find(params[:id])
>       @asurvey.destroy
>
> ```
> respond_to do |format|
>   format.html { redirect_to asurveys_url }
>   format.json { head :ok }
> end   end end
> ```

**application_controller.rb**

> class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
>   protect_from_forgery
>
> def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)   stored_location_for(resource) || bienvenido_path end end

**my models**

> ```
>     class User < ActiveRecord::Base
>   # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
>   # :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
>   #codigo de asociacion, un usuario puede tener muchas encuestas, esta asociacio se hace para que 1 usuario pueda
>   #tener muchas encuestas, pero cada encuesta solo tiene 1 usuario
>
>   #codigo de prueba para asociar encuestas a un solo usuario
>   #has_many :asurveys
>   has_many :asurveys
>   #, :foreign_key => :user_id, :class_name => 'User'
>   #fin asociacion
>
>   devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,:confirmable,
>          :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
>
>   # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
>   attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me,
>                   :tipo_tarjeta, :numero_tarjeta, :fecha_vencimiento, :nombre_en_tarjeta,
>                   :cvv, :nombre, :apellidos, :mail_facturacion, :mail_facturacion_alternativo,
>                   :nombre_empresa, :pais, :direccion,:codigo_postal, :telefono, :numero_orden_compra 
>
>                   #validacion de presencia de campos, no pueden estar en blanco
>   #validacion de presencia de campos, no pueden estar en blanco
>   validates_presence_of :numero_tarjeta,
>   :message => ": ingrese numero de tarjeta (15 digitos)"
>   validates_presence_of  :nombre_en_tarjeta,
>   :message => ": ingrese el nombre que aparece en su tarjeta"
>   #validates_presence_of  :fecha_vencimiento,
>   #:message => ": ingrese fecha de vencimiento de su tarjeta"
>   validates_presence_of  :cvv,
>   :message => ": ingrese cvv "
>   #validacion de ingreso de campos "datos personales"
>   validates_presence_of :nombre, 
>   :message => ": ingrese su nombre"
>   validates_presence_of :apellidos,
>   :message => ": ingrese sus apellidos"
>   validates_presence_of :mail_facturacion,
>   :message => ": ingrese mail de facturacion"
>   validates_presence_of :mail_facturacion_alternativo,
>   :message => ": ingrese mail alternativo de facturacion"
>   validates_presence_of :nombre_empresa,
>   :message => ": ingrese nombre de su empresa"
>   validates_presence_of :direccion,
>   :message => ": ingrese direccion de su empresa"
>    validates_presence_of :codigo_postal,
>   :message => ": ingrese codigo postal"
>   validates_presence_of :telefono,
>   :message => ": ingrese telefono de su empresa"
>   validates_presence_of :numero_orden_compra,
>   :message => ": ingrese numero de orden de compra"
>   #largo de campos, formato mail
>   validates_length_of :numero_tarjeta, :minimum => 16, :allow_blank => true, :message => "El numero debe tener al menos 16
> ```
>
> digitos de longitud"
>         validates_length_of :nombre_en_tarjeta, :minimum => 2, :allow_blank => true, :message => "minimo 2 caracteres"
>         validates_length_of :cvv, :in => 3..4, :allow_blank => true, :message => "(en Mastercard y Visa son los 3 ultimos digitos impresos
>   al dorso de la tarjeta, en American Express son los 4 numeros impresos
>   en el frente de la tarjeta arriba de los ultimos digitos grabados en
>   relieve)" 
>         validates_length_of :nombre, :minimum => 2, :allow_blank => true, :message => "minimo 2 caracteres" 
>         validates_length_of :apellidos, :minimum => 4, :allow_blank => true, :message => "minimo 4 caracteres" 
>         validates_format_of :mail_facturacion,
>         :with => /^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@([A-Z0-9]+.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$/i, :message => "formato incorrecto"
>         validates_format_of :mail_facturacion_alternativo,
>         :with => /^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@([A-Z0-9]+.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$/i, :message => "formato incorrecto en mail alternativo"
>         validates_length_of :nombre_empresa, :minimum => 4, :allow_blank => true, :message => "minimo 4 caracteres" 
>         validates_length_of :direccion, :minimum => 4, :allow_blank => true, :message => "minimo 4 caracteres"
>         validates_length_of :codigo_postal, :minimum => 7, :allow_blank => true, :message => "minimo 7 caracteres" 
>         validates_length_of :telefono, :minimum => 7, :allow_blank => true, :message => "minimo 7 caracteres" 
>         validates_length_of :numero_orden_compra, :minimum => 2, :allow_blank => true, :message => "minimo 2 caracteres"
>
> ```
>   #validates_length_of :password, :minimum => 6, :allow_blank => false
> ```
>
> ### >     end
>
> class Asurvey < ActiveRecord::Base   #asociacion para que las
>   encuestas puedan ser vistas solo por el usuario que la crea
>
> ## belongs_to :user   #belongs_to :user   #belongs_to :user, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => 'user_id'   belongs_to :user   #, :foreign_key => "user_id"   #attr_accessible :user_id   #has_many
>
> :asurveys_users   #has_many :users, :through => :asurveys_users
>
> ## has_many :asurveys_users, :class_name => "User", :through => :asurveys_users   #fin asociacion, una encuesta pertenece a solo un
>
> usuario   has_many :questions, :dependent => :destroy   #:dependent =>
>   :destroy para que cuando eliminemos una encuesta se eliminen también
>   todas sus preguntas.   accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions,
>   :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:content].blank? } , :allow_destroy =>
>   true      #accepts_nested_attributes_for para poder gestionar las
>   preguntas a través de Survey. Con esto podremos crear, actualizar y
>   destruir preguntas cuando actualicemos los atributos de una encuesta.
>
> ## el nombre de atributo para la caja de selección: _destroy. Cuando tenga un valor true (cuando haya sido marcada), el registro será
>
> eliminado al enviar el formulario.   #User.find(1).asurveys   end

*views*

> ## Encuesta
>
> **Nombre:**     <%=h
>   @asurvey.name %>
>
>   <% for question in
>     @asurvey.questions %>
> 1. <%= h question.content %>
>     <% for answer in question.answers %>
>   - <%= h answer.content %>
>     <% end %>
>   <% end %>
>
> <%= link_to "Editar", edit_asurvey_path(@asurvey) %> |     <%= link_to "Eliminar",
>   @asurvey, :confirm => 'Estas seguro/a?', :method => :delete %> |
>   <%= link_to "Ver todas las encuestas", asurveys_path %>

**asurvey_helper**

> module AsurveysHelper end

Comment: There are a lot if code. Please, paste it [here][1] and it will be more comfortably to see it and review your code. Also it would be perfect if you paste `db/schema.rb` file. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create new surveys you should do something like this:

```
current_user.asurveys.create(params[:assurvey])
```

To get the surveys created only by the loged user:

```
@asurveys = current_user.asurveys
```

Comment: thanks! but...I need a current_user helper? what is the sintax?

Comment: You don't need the create current_user method. The current_user helper method is created automatically by the Devise gem.

Comment: ok thanks...but...don´t works! of course I'm doing something wrong...please help!!! what other piece of code could help???

Comment: ok here we go: in mysql alter table asurveys add foreign key (user_id) references users(id);

Answer (score 0):

After "@asurvey = Asurvey.new(params[:asurvey])", you need set the user before save @asurvey, like:

```
@asurvey = Asurvey.new(params[:asurvey])
@asurvey.user = current_user
```